# How to add pod to local pod project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project with multiple local pod files.The issue I am facing is with enabling fabric sdk in those pod files. The reason is due to the fact that I am using pod installation for fabric. So my main target(project) files can

```
import Fabric
```

But this is not possible inside pod file I am using locally. It's not available to my local pod. How could we add fabric to local pod.

Any help please !!

Comment: You need to configure in your .podspec your sub frameworks for your pod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your PodProject.podspec the following before `end` keyword.

```
s.dependency 'Fabric'
```

That's how you link other pod requirements with your pod project.

Comment: target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: 
Getting this error after adding s.dependency 'Fabric' in .podspec